# SDL Tridion and SDL Quatron - version compatibility

Tags: 2013, installation

Could someone help clear up a question regarding SDL Tridion and SDL Quatron compatibility. The current documentation for Quatron (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent) claims the following regarding the SDL Tridion integration prerequisites....

> SDL Quatron supports the following versions of SDL Tridion:
>
> Content Manager of SDL Tridion 2009
>
> Content Manager of SDL Tridion 2011

I've heard that it is also compatible with SDL Tridion 2013. Hoping someone can confirm or deny.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has been some changes in the eventsystem handling in SDL Tridion 2013 (async handling) that prevents the 2011 Tridion integration from functioning correctly so you will need an updated version of the eventsystem that takes care of the synchronization between Tridion and Quatron. Today this is not product but we use it in the CXC demo.